# MySQL Query Count()

Tags: php, mysql

When I try this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS `unique`, impressions 
             FROM statistic 
             WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time_add, '%d.%m.%Y') = '" . date('d.m.Y', time()) . "'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I see this error message:

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

I don't know what is this error and I think someone can help me here :).

Comment: error seems clear, cant use aggregate function with out a group by clause: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have count(id) for the specific impressions?
You might need to add group by impresions because you cannot use Count function and impression in the same time impression should be presented in group by statement.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: PDO or MySQLi is more better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line after the `WHERE` clause

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS `unique`, impressions 
             FROM statistic 
             WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time_add, '%d.%m.%Y') = '" . date('d.m.Y', time()) . "'
             GROUP BY impressions") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

count is a group function and you can't select another column with count unless mentioned in group clause.

```
  mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS `unique`, impressions FROM 
statistic WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time_add, '%d.%m.%Y') = '" . date('d.m.Y', time()) . "' 
GROUP BY impressions")
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are using a column in `COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG` aggregation functions, you have to mention that column in `GROUP BY` clause like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS `unique`, impressions FROM statistic WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(time_add, '%d.%m.%Y') = '" . date('d.m.Y', time()) . "' GROUP BY id") or die(mysql_error());
```

P.S. mysql_* functions are deprecated, it is safer to use PDO or MySQLi functions to avoid sql-injections and other sql violations.

Comment: The column used in an aggregate function isn't what needs to be used in the `group by` clause - using an aggregate function will default to grouping by all columns, but the second column selected (`impressions` in this case) is *not* an aggregate function and will need grouping in order to work in the query

Comment: "' GROUP BY id" This doesn't work. You need to use Group by impressions to make that work as pointed below.